# How to filter a product is in multiple category?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The objective is, I have some products and each product is under multiple categories. Initially I list all product and I need to filter by jQuery. I've tried the following method but it seems not working. can anyone tell me how can I achieve this ?

```
<section class="container">
    <ul class="filters">
        <li><a href="" class="nav-filter" data-filters='{"filterObject": [{"items": "hdtv,usb-30"}]}'>HD TV</a></li>
        <li><a href="" class="nav-filter" data-filters='{"filterObject": [{"items": "hdtv,android-tv"}]}'>FULL-HD</a></li>
        <li><a href="" class="nav-filter" data-filters='{"filterObject": [{"items": "android-tv,usb-30"}]}'>USB 3.0</a></li>
        <li><a href="" class="nav-filter" data-filters='{"filterObject": [{"items": "hdtv,full-hd"}]}'>Android</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div id="products">
        <div class="items" data-filter='hdtv,usb-30'>
            <h2>I am HDTV haing usb 3.0</h2>
        </div>

        <div class="items" data-filter='hdtv,android-tv'>
            <h2>I am HDTV but a android tv</h2>
        </div>

        <div class="items" data-filter='android-tv,usb-30'>
           <h2>I am android tv</h2>
        </div>

        <div class="items" data-filter='hdtv,full-hd'>
            <h2>I am a HDTV and full HD tv</h2>
        </div>
    </div>

</section>
```

This is my jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".nav-filter").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".items").hide();
        _ = $(this);
        filteritem = _.data("filters");         
        if(_.attr("data-status")=="active"){
            _.attr("data-status","");
            _.removeClass("active");
        }else{
            _.attr("data-status","active")
            _.addClass("active");
        }
        count = 0;
        $( ".filters" ).find("li").each(function() {
                elem  = $(this).find("[data-status='active']");
                item_show = elem.data("filters");       
                item = item_show.filterObject[0].items.split(",");  
                debugger;   
                if(typeof item_show === "undefined"){ count++; }                            
                if(count == $( ".filters" ).find("li").length){ $(".items").show(); }               
                else{                   
                    $("#products").find("div").each(function(){
                            in_Array = $(this).data("filter").split(",");
                            if((item[0]==in_Array[0] || item[1]==in_Array[1]) || (item[0]==in_Array[1] || item[1]==in_Array[0])){
                                //$(this).show();
                            }                           
                    });
                }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Just a sidenote: beware that this line `_ = $(this);` is forcing `_` to leave the local scope of the function. Use `var _ = $(this);` to assure that you are working with a local `this pointer`.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a filter logic like

```js
var $items = $('#products .items').each(function() {
  var values = $(this).data('filter').split(/\s*,\s*/);
  $(this).data('array-filters', values);
});
$('.filters li:has([data-filters])').click(function() {
  var filters = $(this).data('array-filters');

  var $selected = $items.filter(function() {
    var values = $(this).data('array-filters');
    return values.some(function(value) {
      return filters.indexOf(value) > -1;
    });
  });

  $selected.show();
  $items.not($selected).hide();

  return false;
}).each(function() {
  var filters = $(this).find('a').data('filters').filterObject[0].items;
  filters = filters.split(/\s*,\s*/);
  $(this).data('array-filters', filters);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="container">
  <ul class="filters">
    <li><a href="" class="nav-filter" data-filters='{"filterObject": [{"items": "hdtv,usb-30"}]}'>HD TV</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="" class="nav-filter" data-filters='{"filterObject": [{"items": "hdtv,android-tv"}]}'>FULL-HD</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="" class="nav-filter" data-filters='{"filterObject": [{"items": "android-tv,usb-30"}]}'>USB 3.0</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="" class="nav-filter" data-filters='{"filterObject": [{"items": "hdtv,full-hd"}]}'>Android</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <div id="products">
    <div class="items" data-filter='hdtv,usb-30'>
      <h2>I am HDTV haing usb 3.0</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="items" data-filter='hdtv,android-tv'>
      <h2>I am HDTV but a android tv</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="items" data-filter='android-tv,usb-30'>
      <h2>I am android tv</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="items" data-filter='hdtv,full-hd'>
      <h2>I am a HDTV and full HD tv</h2>
    </div>
  </div>

</section>
```

Comment: This is not what I expected. for eg if I click HDTV I need to show only the HDTV and the HDTV is selected. and if I select USB 3.0 I need to show the HDTV and USB 3.0. because the HDTV is selected before.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try the following

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".nav-filter").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".items").hide();
        _ = $(this);
        var filteritem = _.data("filters");
        var item = filteritem.filterObject[0].items.split(',');
        $("#products").find("div").each(function () {

            for (var i = 0; i < item.length; i++) {
                if ($(this).data("filter").indexOf(item[i]) >= 0) {
                    $(this).show();

                }
            }

        });

    });

 });
```

[Fiddler](https://jsfiddle.net/t9gb7ens/9/)

Comment: This is not what I expected. for eg if I click HDTV I need to show only the HDTV and the HDTV is selected. and if I select USB 3.0 I need to show the HDTV and USB 3.0. because the HDTV is selected before.

Comment: @Qustions Stack If click on HD TV what output you are expecting and after that I click FULL-HD what should be the output, Can you please elaborate

Comment: if I click HDTV I need to show only the HDTV and the HDTV as selected item. and if I select USB 3.0 I need to show the HDTV and USB 3.0.

Comment: @QustionsStack Can you please let me know if click on HD TV what divs under id "Products" I need to show and similarly when I click on USB 3.0.Can you please check https://jsfiddle.net/t9gb7ens/8/